# C code explanation needed

Tags: c, square-root

Can someone explain the following code? 
what is the use of the variable ort?

```
void squart_root(double a)
{
if (a>0.0){
    double root = 1, ort = 0;
    while(ort!=root)
    {
        ort = root;
        root = ((a/root) + root) / 2;
    }
    printf("Root is : %lf",root);
}else if(a==0.00000){
    printf("Root is : %lf",a);
}else{
    printf("Cannot find the square root of a negative number");
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it calculates the square root of a number.  What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots, first "big" equation, better explained further down. The `while` goes on with the sequence until the computation exceeds the precision of `double`.

Comment: yes I can understand that. I need what is the algorithm and how it executed line by line?

Comment: What's so difficult? At each iteration `ort` is `x_n`, while `root` is `x_{n+1}`; the `while` stops when `x_n==x_{n+1}`, i.e. when we reached a point in the sequence where the precision of the `double` data type doesn't admit to go further in the sequence.

Comment: Use a debugger.  Step through it line by line.

Comment: This is a numerical method for finding square root of numbers. I am not sure but I think this is 'bisection method'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks similar to Newton's method of calculating square root (derived from Newton-Raphson's method).

You can read more about this [here](http://www.school-for-champions.com/algebra/square_root_approx.htm#.UnxcOfvY-PU).

It looks like:

```
  X(n+1) = (A/X(n) + X(n))/2
  It converges when X(n) = X(n+1) (that is in your case) or under some precision.
```

At each iteration, X(n) should get closer to the real root.

The purpose of `ort` is to hold X(n) and check for this convergence. When root converges, loop terminates. That is why `ort` is here.

You can read about Newton-Raphsone method (just google it) and you will be able to derive this equation.